# dragging effect using easeljs

Tags: javascript, easeljs

I've just started to learn easeljs. I have tried to create a rectangle which will follow the mouse coordinates, but it is not working. What's wrong here and how it can be fixed?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humptydumpty45/5Cgk5/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
</style>
<script src="easeljs.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
<script>
function init(){

var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
var stage=new createjs.Stage(canvas);
var shape=new createjs.Shape();
shape.graphics.beginFill('red').drawRect(300,200,40,40);
stage.addChild(shape);

 createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick",tick);
function tick(event){
shape.x=stage.mouseX;
shape.y=stage.mouseY;

stage.update(event);

}
}
window.onload=init;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the x and y of your rectangle to be 300 and 200 respectively, so if you set those to 0, then the rectangle will start in the right place and follow the mouse as expected.

```
shape.graphics.beginFill('red').drawRect(0,0,40,40);
```